# Caching media objects in android

Tags: android, image, caching, audio

I'm developping an app that permits the user to listen some podcasts. The app is downloading content from a server such as descriptions, images and also stream from an URL an audio flow.

I'd like to implement a cache which would save all these podcast objects containing basic types (such as strings for the description for example) but also the image linked to the podcast and the podcast itself (audio flow).

If I had to compare this to any other app it would probably be the Soundcloud app which does all this.

I searched on the web to find some tutorials or good pratices but these are explaining the basic way to cache basic objects. Also I found Volley but this is bad for streaming audio or things like that.

If anyone could help, it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for? I'm looking for something similar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache them in memory use `LruCache`, if you want to cache them on disk use `DiskLruCache`. Check this [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) and this [DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache).

Comment: Yep I was aware of this, but what about audio ? 
I'd like some advices about structuring the cache (optimization or structure between different media (description, audio, image)). Thanks anyway.